# Is there a way to see which table is being run in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've got an Azure Data Factory pipeline that does a lookup of a couple of schemas and copies their data over to a new database. I can see that- whenever I go to run it- each table that it copies, has an instance I can see in the logs of the run.

Example:

[image]

I can click on these and get more information, although it doesn't tell me, exactly, which table it's running. Is there a way I can map an instance to a specific table?

Comment: Clicking on the input arrow would give you the table details ( one to the left of binocular icon?)

Answer (score 1):

- Query option in source dataset is selected and query is given in query textbox as in below image.
  [image]
- When pipeline is run,  click on the input of the copy activity in the log.
  [image]
- In SQLReaderQuery, you can find the source table name of that activity.
  [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see sqlReaderQuery in my input JSON. It's a longer query, would that be the difference? Or is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: UPDATE: looking around in that input option, I can probably deduce the tables because I'm using upsert and in the input JSON, it tells me which keys are being used. However, I don't see sqlReadyQuery. Thank you for the tip